# Adding complexity to a webscrapper

Tags: javascript

How can I further automate my web-scrapper? Currently it can search singular constant urls. How do I add a function that makes it search multiple pages within a constant website.

Here is my code

```
const PORT = 8000
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')

const app = express ()

const url = 'heresurdata'

axios(url)
     .then(response => {
      const html = response.data
      console.log(html)

})

app.listen (PORT, () => console.log('server running on PORT ${PORT}'))
```

Comment: Welcome to so, please ask one specific question not a question with a load of opiniated answers.

Comment: I specifically wanted to make it search multiple pages within a given website. Could you give me some insight on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make a request to the first page find all the anchor tags get their links make request to them and repeat the process

```js
const {data} = await axios.get(url);

const $ = cheerio.load(data);

const allLinkTags = $('body a').map((index, el) => $(el).attr('href')).get();

// Now look through all the link tags and scrape them
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll give it a try. I'm fairly new to coding and webscraping any personal sources you'd recommend for a newbie?

Comment: Just search for the specific questions that you have at the moment you encounter them for example (cheerio get elements attribute), that's my personal best resource, Good luck and if the answer was the one you looking for mark the answer as accepted answr